# ControlCommand in AutoIt v3

Tags: autoit

I am trying to use ControlCommands with a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application (hence, these should all be standard Microsoft controls), but most of the ones that are of interest don't seem to do anything.

I am currently looking at a combobox (the drop down box). I used the "showdropdown" command to have it drop down, and it worked successfully.

I then tried to use "SelectString", but it didn't go to the string that I specified. How does the "SelectString" ControlCommand option work?

I have also tried "SetCurrentSelection".

This is the statement I used:

```
ControlCommand($windowName, "", "[Name:myComboBox]", "SelectString", "a")
```

I have also tried searching for it first with:

```
ControlCommand($windowName, "", "[Name:myComboBox]", "FindString", "a")
```

but it didn't find it either. Strange, the single character "a" is there.

If it helps, this is the control class: WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_GUICtrlComboBox_xxx` functions also work on external controls. For example, `_GUICtrlComboBox_FindString`, `_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString`, `_GUICtrlComboBox_SetCurSel`. Try those instead.

Call `ControlGetHandle` first, then use this handle to call the functions above.

Remember to include the `GuiComboBox` library, otherwise you will get an error message "Error: Unknown function name":

```
#include <GuiComboBox.au3>
```

Comment: I just read about the GuiComboBox.a3u library and have tried out some of the functions. It worked nicely!

Comment: Can you please give some practical example of how to do this..I am having the same problem. trying _GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString("[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", 'Business Processor (CBT QWERTYGP COMPOUND) - QTY00")

Answer (score 0):

You can send key presses to this control, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45929499/11725753):

```
ControlSend("Window title", "", "[NAME:comboBoxName]", "ComboBox value")
```

It works because ComboBox interprets input as a search string and selects the first item starting with this string.

> **Note:** Because it searches the matching item as you type, there's no need to send a complete value, only the shortest substring.