# How to choose value from dropdown (combobox)?

Tags: autoit

I am automating a Windows application using AutoIt. I tried to select a value from a drop down menu, but I'm unable to. My code:

```
ControlCommand("Database Select","", "[Name:db_comboBox]", "ShowDropDown")
ControlCommand("DatabaseSelect","","Name:db_comboBox]","SelectString",'Test')
ControlCommand("Database Select","Main Load Settings", "[Name:db_comboBox]", "HideDropDown")
```

How to choose a value from dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milos, Thanks for your help and the below code solved my case.

```
  ControlClick("Database Select", "", "[Name:db_comboBox]")
  While 1
    Send("{DOWN}")
    $ctext=ControlGetText("Database Select","","[Name:db_comboBox]")
    If $ctext="DB_UKTEST" Then
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
  WEnd
```

Comment: **Beware**: Make sure to add a security guard like a counter or something before running this script or even better, evaluate `@error` after the `ControlGetText()` call and exit the loop if there's any. Otherwise you might end up in a loop that endlessly moves the cursor down.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
ControlSend("Print", "", "ComboBox1", "[Name:Microsoft Print to PDF]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Example code of selecting the value in dropdown.

```
Run("calc.exe")

WinWait("Calculator")

$CALC = WinGetHandle("Calculator")

ControlSend($CALC, "", "[INSTANCE:1]", "^u")
WinActivate($CALC)

$index = ControlCommand($CALC,"Find String","[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]","FindString",'Volume')
ControlCommand($CALC, "", "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]", "SetCurrentSelection", $index)
```

When applied to your code:

```
$index = ControlCommand("Database Select","", "[Name:db_comboBox]","FindString",'Test')
ControlCommand("Database Select","", "[Name:db_comboBox]", "SetCurrentSelection", $index)
```

Comment: Hi Milos, Thanks for the response, but my query is to choose an item from drop down, 'ControlListView' command not working for my Scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This Work For Me :

```
WinWaitActive ("Options (User-Mode)")
ControlCommand("Options (User-Mode)" , "" , "ComboBox1" , "SelectString" , "VNC password")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
ControlCommand("Database Select","", "[Name:db_comboBox]", "SelectString", $your_text_value)
```